# Different results from running cmd command in shell and through PHP?

Tags: php, html, npm, cmd, command-line

I have installed [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text) through Node.js . When I run the following command in the shell:

> C:\> html-to-text < D:\test.html --tables=true --wordwrap=false > D:\test.txt

the file `D:\\test.html` is properly converted to txt and I find the proper output next to it in `D:\\` folder.
However, if I try to run exactly the same command through PHP on my local server:

```
<?php
exec('html-to-text < D:\\test.html --tables=true --wordwrap=false > D:\\test.txt');
?>
```

The script runs and produces a .txt file, but the .txt file is empty.

What causes this different behavior? How should I run the script through PHP and get the proper result instead of empty file? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You could try to run a batch script containing that line - there are some other questions about this topic that mention that the redirection does not work properly using `exec`

Comment: Perhaps drive `D:` doesn't exist in the context the code runs in; have you already tried a UNC alternative?

Comment: @NicoHaase I put the command in a bat file and called the file from PHP. Unfortunately, it gave the same result... empty output txt.

Comment: @aschipfl The script actually runs and puts a txt file into `D:`, but somehow it is empty instead of containing the output. Which seems to mean that `D:` is accessible from context...